# What year should I put in the "year" field in @inproceedings?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Suppose that I am writing an entry for a paper in a conference proceeding by using `@inproceedings`.  The conference took place in 2005, but its proceeding came out as a book in 2006.  What year should I put in the `year` field of the entry?

Comment: The year the proceedings were published; 2006 in your case.

Comment: this is more an editorial question than a tex question.  however, ..., the year field in a bib entry, even `@inproceedings`, is the year of publication, hence 2006.  (a more "extended" entry would have a separate field for the conference year, but i don't believe bibtex offers that; don't know about biblatex.)

Comment: `biblatex` has `eventdate` field to record the date (year) when a conference  happened.

Comment: Often, especially, in the 'extended' title of a Proceedings collection, the subtitle (or perhaps, to use `biblatex` terminology, as a 'titleaddon') will include information about the event. E.g. (using all three fields), `title={Titles and Conferences}, subtitle={When Will the Ambiguities End?}, titleaddon={Proceedings of a Conference on Bibliographical Problems, Rome, 19--21 January, 2017},`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is more an editorial question than a tex question. however, ...

the year field in a bib entry, even @inproceedings, is the year of publication,
hence 2006.

a more "extended" entry would have a separate field for the conference year.  in a comment, Guido reports that `biblatex` has the `eventdate` field to record the date
when a conference took place.
another comment, by jon, provides additional useful commentary.